# When extending a jQuery UI widget, how to extend more than one function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm currently extending the jQuery UI widget as follows:

```
$.widget( "custom.autocompleteCategorized", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    }    
});
```

This works fine, but I would now like to extend another function like so:

```
$.widget( "custom.autocompleteCategorized", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
    }

    _response: function(contents){
        $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response.apply(this, arguments);
        $(this.element).trigger("autocompletesearchcomplete", [contents]);
    }

});
```

Unfortunately this errors, what is the right way to extend multiple functions as seen above?

Thanks

Comment: looks to me as if you're missing a comma

Comment: Thanks I tried that but then I get a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" after entering input in the autocompleter

Comment: Well, that's how you do it, though, more or  less. Maybe something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing comma i think

```
$.widget( "custom.autocompleteCategorized", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });

    }, // <--- you're missing this comma

    _response: function(contents){
        $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._response.apply(this, arguments);
        $(this.element).trigger("autocompletesearchcomplete", [contents]);
    }

});
```